# outliers for right heavy tails distribtuions

Tags: distributions, outliers, heavy-tailed

There is plenty of information on how to detect outliers in a sample when assuming that this sample was derived from a normal distribution.
Sometimes it seems to me as if when we talk about outliers it just means deviation from a normal distribution.

But if we speak about right heavy tails distribution of the population, so that, say, we sampled a sample out of this heavy tail distribution

**conceptually, what does it mean for a data point to be an outlier in that case?**
meaning, if the data point is very far to the right, it can still be regarded as part of the right heavy tail distribution.

So what types of outliers should I look for in a heavy tail right distribution?

Is there any statistical method that I can use?

Comment: Not in general, because you set an impossible standard.  By calling a distribution "heavy tailed" you are asserting -- in a non-quantitative way -- that you expect some extreme values; but then you ask, in effect, how to identify "more than extreme" values.  No progress is possible until you are more specific and clear.

Comment: I don't find that most discussions of outliers start with a premise that the parent is a normal distribution. But the chicken and egg question is what distribution do you expect -- for all a sample or most of it -- as a reference distribution for deciding what is or is not an outlier.

Comment: For what it’s worth, [here](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2014/06/02/hate-stepwise-regression/), Andrew Gelman describes outlier detection as a notion that, despite being popular among non-statisticians, is considered to be “a bit of a joke” by statisticians. (The rest of the post is on a totally different topic.)